# Get a new shipping tab in magento 1.7 show on the front end

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to add an in store pickup option but only for two locations.  I have made a tab for these two in the admin backend ( I copied the free shipping method and renamed it instore in system.xml and changed the config.xml to add the instore section), but I can only show one method correctly(freeshipping).  When I enable the free shipping method and the instore method, I get two copies of free shipping.  When I only enable the instore method I get nothing.
What do I need to adjust to show the two separate options?

**EDIT** I found the pickup shipping method in the files, but it is not active in the admin section, so enabling this would be another option if I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this task, I ended up using the free shipping option for one location, and found an in store pick up page that was not in use. After some simple modifications I was able to have both options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom shipping option I recommand to use the Owebia Shipping2 extension 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-2.html

If this solution doesn't fit your needs please provide the part of code you put in your system.xml file and we'll try to correct it ;)

Regards,